# Problem with complex equation $\sin z=\cos z$

Tags: complex-analysis

I attempted to solve $\sin{z} = \cos{z}$
I used Eulero formulas for complex sin and cos. Then, in order to eliminate \i from sin's denominator, I raised to square, but then I get an impossible equation. Is it the right way?

Edit: I saw another discussion, but I want understand if my method is correct

Comment: Does dividing both sides by $\cos(z)$ help at all?

Comment: I saw other discussion but I would know if my method is correct